# Graphcms what's Use as title field

Tags: graphcms

I don't understand what's it for
**Use as title field** in graphcms model.
Could you explain to me a give me an example, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Displays this field's value instead of the ID in relations"

By default, it shows id in relation.

[image: By default shows id in relation]

After setting a field as the title of a model

[image: After setting a field as the title of a model]

it shows the value of the "title" field in relation.

[image: shows the value of the "title" field in relation]